# Backslash missing in file while replace the string content using backslash contain variable

Tags: bash, scripts, text-processing, sed

I want to write backslashes in a file, and I try to substitute some text with the value from a variable:

```
$ TEST=\\etc\\hello
$ echo $TEST
\etc\hello
```

But the backslash is missing when I tying to replace them using `sed -i`

```
$ sed -i "s/target_value/$TEST/" $(pwd)/test.txt
results "etchello" in test.txt
```

I expect the file to contain `\etc\hello`.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: See this question it may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722316/how-to-pass-backslashes-argument-to-a-script

Comment: Ubuntu Version 20.02

Comment: There is no 20.02

Comment: Sorry David, Correct version is VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"

Comment: Can't reproduce this. If I perform your `sed` command, I get `No such file or directory`. Make sure to provide a scenario that easily can be reproduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `sed` interpreting the `\` in your variable as an escape character. You can escape special characters using `printf %q`:

```
sed -i "s/target_value/$(printf %q "$TEST")/" test.txt
```

Alternatively, your scenario would have worked if you had defined your variable as:

```
TEST='\\etc\\hello'
```

Note the single quotes around the sting, that causes `$TEST` to contain the literal string.

Comment: No, it's _sed_ interpreting the backslash that causes the problem. After `TEST=\\etc\\hello`, they have `\etc\hello` in the variable, just as they show and appear to want. That's what goes to sed in `sed -i "s/target_value/$TEST/"`, and sed that interprets C-style escapes like `\n`, and `\\` (but not `\e`, apparently).

Comment: Not sure of that. afaik it is bash that first interprets your command (expanding variables, escaping characters) before the command sees the arguments. As the search/replace string is double quoted, it is first processed by bash.

Comment: I am. Bash processes the backslashes in the assignment `TEST=\\etc\\hello`, that's why they need them doubled there. It does also process backslashes within double quotes, but _not_ ones that come as a result of an expansion. And anyway, `"\etc\hello"` becomes `\etc\hello`, it's just the kinds of `"\$"` and `"\""` that have the backslash removed. Try `printf "%s\n" "$TEST"` and `echo | sed 's/^/\etc\hello/'`.

Comment: @ilkkachu Indeed I agree - tested a bit and an `\n` becomes a new line. I will update, thanks!

Comment: command sed -i "s/target_value/$(printf %q "$TEST")/" test.txt  works fine for adding backslash in the test.txt, If $TEST variable contain "\n" along with the backslash content then it is printing it in test.txt instead of adding a new line.

Comment: Yes, because the entire string is converted to preserve all characters, i.e. in `\n`, the `\` is escaped (becomes `\\` and `n` is preserved. Preparing the string appropriately, e.g. `TEST=$LINE1"\n"$LINE2` and then performing the command will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shell parameter substitution to escape the backslashes. Ex.:

```
$ set -x
+ set -x

$ echo 'foo target_value bar' | sed "s/target_value/${TEST//\\/\\\\}/"
+ echo 'foo target_value bar'
+ sed 's/target_value/\\etc\\hello/'
foo \etc\hello bar
```

See also:

- [sed: Substituting text pattern containing backslash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/618706/sed-substituting-text-pattern-containing-backslash)